# Chrome options Proxy Bypass List not working

Tags: selenium, chrome-options

I've been trying to add arguments to my Chrome Options to use a proxy and to ignore certain URL's.

I've followed the documentation and am trying to run this very simple test:

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8080");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=http://www.google.com");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/drivers/chromeDriver/win/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

}

I've also tried with the variation:

```
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

But it won't open the URL, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use `chromedriver.exe` instead of `eclipse.exe` while setting property and make sure you have compatible chromedriver as per current version available in your system.

Here we go :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8080");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=https://www.google.com");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver_location\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: That was just a typo (I've edited the original post). The code doesn't work for me, I get a "This site can't be reached" error. When I take out the "options.addArguments" lines of code, then it laucnhes the site without errors.